Как реализовать white-list в телеграм боте?
Есть Aiogram бот, в котором хочу осуществить условный «White list».
То-есть, при запуске бота, не авторизированный юзер не должен ничего сделать кроме как авторизоваться в нем.
Пытался реализовать это через миддлвейр, но понял что этот подход у меня на каждое обновление делает запрос в базу. А если одновременно юзеров будет 100?
Может кто-то из вас сталкивался с такой проблемой, или имеет пару мыслей как это обыграть?

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.
